# Fetch PDF file from database and display it on Windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I want to fetch a PDF file from database using its location and display it on my form application. I watched many Youtube videos but none of it helped me with my problem.What is the other way that I can try to do this?

```
string f = comboBox2.Text;
string qu = "SELECT location FROM attachments WHERE name='" + f + "'";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(qu, con);
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    var input = reader["location"].ToString();
    this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(input);
}
```

My database table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[attachments]  
(
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [idno]     INT           NULL,
    [name]     VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [location] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
```

I am not getting any help from any video with this problem. Any suggestions how can I improve this code?

Comment: Your database field would probably be better as some sort of Binary type. Then you can get from the database as a byte[] array and use a method like File.WriteAllBytes to write to disk.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change location field to VarBinary.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[attachments] (
[Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[idno]     INT           NULL,
[name]     VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[location] VARBINARY (MAX) NULL
);
```

Use byte array if the LoadFile method will accept it else write to disk...

```
string f = comboBox2.Text;
string qu = "SELECT location FROM attachments WHERE name=@name";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(qu, con);
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", f);
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    var file = (byte[])reader["location"];
    this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(file);
    //else use a method like 'File.WriteAllBytes(file);'
}
```